# wrong number or types of arguments in call to procedure (PLS00306)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedure, cursors

```
create or replace procedure flight_search(
v_source in flights.origin_ap%type,
v_destination in flights.destination_ap%type,
v_date in flights.depart_date%type,
v_flightid out flights.flightid%type,
v_fare out flights.fare%type)
 is
cursor search_flight is SELECT flightid FROM flights
where v_source = origin_ap and v_destination = destination_ap and v_date = 
depart_date;
begin

open search_flight;
loop
fetch search_flight into v_flightid;
exit when search_flight%NOTFOUND;
dbms_output.put_line('Leaves from - ' || v_source || '. Arrives at - ' || 
v_destination || '. Fare - ' || v_fare);
end loop;
close search_flight;
end;
```

executing by

```
execute flight_search('JFK', 'LHR', '11/25/18');
```

Getting wrong number or types of arguments in call to flight_search. I am assuming it has something to do with the flightid and fare variables.

Answer (score 1):

Your procedure has 5 formal arguments, and your call only has 3. You need to supply somewhere for the `out` variables to go. As you seem to be using SQL*Plus or SQL Developer, judging by the `execute`, you can use bind variables and then print those out after the call:

```
variable l_flightid number;
variable l_fare number;

execute flight_search('JFK', 'LHR', date '2018-11-25', l_flightid, l_fare);

print l_flightid
```

I've also changed the third argument to an actual date, rather than a string which has to be implicitly converted to a date using your current session NLS settings. I've used a [date literal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1), but you could also use `to_date()` with a string literal and a suitable format mask.

Incidentally, you aren't currently populating `v_fare`. so I haven't bothered printing that variable after the call; and it isn't obvious where it would come from. And you might want to consider using an implicit cursor loop instead of an explicit one.